# Cosmos Emulator randomly failing tests on Linux

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, specflow

I'm trying to run Cosmos Emulator on Linux, to run tests using SpecFlow.

After installing it following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#run-on-linux), and successfully running it, a variable number of tests randomly failed all the times I tried to run them.

The failed tests throw a `CosmosException` with a `503 (Service Unavailable)` status code.

All these tests work just fine on Windows and, depending on how I run them, either via the terminal or VSCode, the number of failures differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the docker command provided within the documentation:

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254  -m 3g --cpus=2.0 --name=test-linux-emulator -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=$ipaddr -it mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

More specifically, with this environment variable:

```
AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10
```

This partition count was too low, which caused it to drop requests. Increasing it to `20`, as suggested in [this Github thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/817#issuecomment-927133201), solved the issue.

I also increased the `--cpus` to `3.0` and the memory `-m` to `4g`, just to be safe.

**EDIT:** Ended up having to increase to `40`. It never broke again after that.